# Displaying List of ViewModel data in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a list of ViewModel which also contains list of other models. I am working on a pre built database which i cant change the structure. I am having difficulties displaying the ViewModel data in razor.

*MyBigViewModel definition*

```
public class MyBigViewModel
    {
        public List<FirstModel> FirstModel { get; set; }
        public List<SecondModel> SecondModel { get; set; }
        public List<ThirdModel> ThirdModel { get; set; }
        public List<FourthModel> FourthModel { get; set; }
        public List<FifthModel> FifthModel { get; set; }

    }
```

I have some buisness logic and based on a query(based on a single model) i will try to populate the view model.

```
List<MyBigViewModel> BigViewModel = new List<MyBigViewModel>();
    foreach (var SingleModel  in FirstModelList)
     {
        SecondModelResult = db.somequery;
        ThirdModelResult = db.somequery;
        FourthModelResult = db.somequery;
        FifthModelResult = db.somequery;

        MyBigViewModel TempViewModel = new MyBigViewModel{
            FirstModel  = FirstModelResult;
            SecondModel = SecondModelResult;
            ThirdModel  = ThirdModelResult;
            FourthModel = FourthModelResult;
            FifthModel  = FifthModelResult;
        }
        BigViewModel.Add(TempViewModel);

      }
```

The result set in `BigViewModel` is exactly the way i wanted it to be structured, but i am unable to display the data in razor using for each. When i try to use  `@foreach (var item in Model)` `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstModel.Name)` is not able to access the data i want.

Comment: That's because  item.FirstModel is a List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `@foreach (var item in Model.FirstModel)` for the loop
And then `@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Name)`

You need to do it this way since you need to iterate over each list of models, not iterate over the single instance of the BigViewModel.